# Hardware for new hosting services

Tags: email, hosting, service, central-processing-unit

i will start a new hosting company but i dont know what hardware will be the best for this. I'm looking for something cheap and can carry about 200-300 hosting accounts. The server will be using for web, mail and hosting server.

QUAD CORE AMD BULLDOZER FX-4130 3.9GHZ 1TB HDD 8GB DDR3 RAM USB 3.0 HDMI, VGA,DVI

Is this hardware is good for about 300 pounds and can this work for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Shopping questions are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @NathanC seems more like a (not so good) capacity planning question rather than a (still not so good) shopping one. While he is giving a price for that, he's not asking for brands or models recommendations.

Comment: Look, these sorts of questions are basically our equivalent of "I'd like to climb Mount Everest. Do I need a coat?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no, you are way far from what you need.

Slightly longer answer is that your question clearly shows you lack experience in this kind of services and are thus not able to correctly plan your hardware deployment. You should hire an experienced sysadmin and/or get an external consultant.

Lets-see-the-bright-side answer: if intermittent service would suffice and your user will hit the mail and web service really infrequently, maybe you could run something on that box.

*(please note: I interpreted your question as if you want to buy exactly a single system. If you're gonna buy lots of them the answer would be different, but still in the negative side)*